# Emacs add quotes around every word

Tags: regex, emacs, replace, expression, elisp

I have a file and i want to add quotes around every word
for example *hello* becomes *"hello"*
So far i have tried this
in emacs:

```
M-x query-replace-regexp [a-z]+ RET "\1" y
```

But it just deletes the word and leaves quotes.

Comment: That's because you're replacing the regexp by the string?

Comment: yeah, but how do i tell him not to delete the regexp? jus to add qoutes around

Answer (score 6):

This is what you want:

```
M-x query-replace-regexp \(\<\w+\>\) RET "\1" y
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to place a capturing group `( )` around your pattern referencing to [back reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Replace.html) `\1`

```
M-x query-replace-regexp \([a-zA-Z]+\) RET "\1" y
```

Answer (score 3):

ok i got it, instead od the \1 I need to put \& in the replace part

Comment: Or use \\(...\\), as in the example I gave. You also need to check word boundaries, using \<...\>.  And you can use \w to represent any word char.